# Trouble with LAMP environment variables ($PATH)

Tags: php, bash, apache, path, environment-variables

I am trying to execute this shell command in bash script 'test.sh'

```
igblastn -query input.txt 2>&1
```

in a php file like this

```
<?php
   $string = "./test.sh";
   $output = shell_exec($string);
   echo "<pre>$output</pre>;
```

and I keep getting the error

```
./test.sh: line 2: igblastn: command not found
```

But when i use more basic commands like 'date' or 'whoami', it outputs just fine. This leads me to believe that either the permissions for the apache web usr 'www-data' need to be configured or I am not pathing correctly to the igblastn executable. I get the error still if I go and test making www-data a superuser for the web server so I don't think it is a problem with permissions and is a problem with pathing. The documentation for the NCBI standalone blast dictates an appendage to the $PATH variable and an introduction of another env variable to the database files in the same folder as the executable file. Currently, I have added the path location to the bin where the executable file is stored as an addition to the PATH variable in /etc/environment on my web server and added the other environment variable and I have also tried adding the another Environment variable to /etc/apache2/envvars but I am still unable to execute. Thus I am wondering if anyone knows definitively where I should create additional environment variables or specify paths for Apache?

Comment: have you tried simply executing the command on the command line?

Comment: Got the latest version installed? ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/blast/executables/igblast/release/ Command not found would suggest it's not installed (to all users?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for anyone that gave me some advice. I decided to run 'env' from my test.sh script and see all the variables. From this I was able to decipher that indeed setting all the variables in /etc/apache2/envvars was the correct approach and I added an appendage to the PATH variable which was my problem to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$PATH` isn't going to matter since the leading  `"./"` is telling your OS to look in the current directory for that script. If you have indeed added that path to `$PATH` you can just remove the `"./"`, otherwise, assuming `test.sh` is in the same directory as the PHP script that's calling it you could just do

```
$string = dirname(realpath(__FILE__))."/test.sh";
$output = shell_exec($string);
```

Comment: @javidaceil PS, welcome to SO, you'll get your first two points when you choose your answer, so if this helps, please hit the checkmark by my answer. You can upvote if you want too :)

Comment: can't believe I missed that. Good eye